# Decode Python strings

Tags: python, string, sqlite, encoding

I have troubles to understand how encodings works:

Why strings inside python code can be encoded:

```
s = 'Au\xc3\x9fenformat\n'
print s.encode('utf-8')
>>>Außenformnat
```

But if I read such a string from a text file I get:

```
f = open('out.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
print data.encode('utf-8')
>>>Au\xc3\x9fenformat\n
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean *decode*? And you are reading from a *text file*, not from a sqlite database here.

Comment: Yes decode (however in the first example it's give me the same result!?). I have the problem with text files and sqlite database, the database example is more complex and I thought it is due to the same problem. I can post it if it is not...

Comment: Before you do, make sure you have read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), then read [this article](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [this one too](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html). The `sqlite3` module handles Unicode fine, but verify the [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) to be sure you didn't accidentally misconfigure things.

Comment: The Howto I read did not solve my problem. Thanks for the other two readings they are more conclusive.

Comment: Does your file actually contain slashes and x'ses? Could you post `cat out.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and you should see the file contents printed correctly:

```
f = open('out.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
print data.decode('string_escape')
```

This is because the backslashes in the txt from the file are being escaped:

```
>>> open('out.txt').read()
'Au\\xc3\\x9fenformat\\n\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> f = open('out.txt', 'r')
>>> data= f.read()
>>> print data.decode("string_escape")
ußenformat
```